# Any option available in Puppeteer to sense complete page download?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

We have been using `page.goto()` with `waitUntil` & `timeout` options of Puppeteer to download the content of the page. But recently we observed that for some urls returning dynamic content(developed using Angular, ReactJs, VueJs, etc.) it is partially returning the page content. Seems like `waitUntil` doesn't have mechanism to sense that entire page content is loaded. We either need to add `await sleep()` or set a higher default timeout in `networkdidle0` option parameter to `page.goto()`. Since the page content is dynamically generated, we cannot preset the `timeout` or `sleep` value.
We are also using `page.content()` which can be used to download the page content. Is there any option parameter available which can help us to get the full content of the page? Or is there any event linked to the `page.content()` which gets triggered once it fetches entire page content?

Comment: The concept of "complete" is, as you say, somewhat nebulous, since JS can run at arbitrary times and fetch more resources and manipulate elements. You get to decide what constitutes "complete" and pull the content at that time. Puppeteer provides various tools to do this: `goto`/`waitForNavigation` can release at `load`, `domcontentloaded`, `networkidle2`, `networkidle0`. Beyond that, there's `waitForSelector`, `waitForFunction`, `waitForRequest`, and if all else fails, `waitForTimeout`, although you almost never need to use that if you're careful and precise.

Comment: If you want a one-size-fits-all solution, there isn't any because every site is unique. If you pick any value of `waitForTimeout`, there's always a site that might take longer to load than that value. And if your value is too high, then you're going to slow all the fast pages unnecessarily. `networkidle2` plus a short timeout is an OK approximation, but any approach will have inaccuracies. It's best to describe your use case a bit clearer so you can manage the tradeoffs appropriately. But yeah, Puppeteer can't possibly have a `waitUntilLoaded` that magically works on all websites ever.